# Is the replacement operator associative?

Tags: replacement

In mathematics, a given operation $\circ$ is said to be *associative* if there is equality
                    $$(f\circ g)\circ h=f\circ(g\circ h)$$
for any $f$, $g$ and $h$. Intuitively, this means that parentheses don't matter when one is dealing with the given operation.

I'm wondering if Mathematica's `ReplaceAll` operator `/.` is associative. Explicitly, suppose that `expr1` is an expression, and `expr2` and `expr3` are replacement rules. Will the Mathematica kernel distinguish between the inputs `(expr1 /. expr2 ) /. expr3` and `expr1 /. (expr2 /. expr3 )`?

Here is an example, which evaluates to `True`:

```
(x /. x -> y) /. y -> z == x /. (x -> y /. y -> z)
```

Is there a nice example of `ReplaceAll` behaving in a non-associative manner? Can I expect associativity under reasonable conditions? What if we consider the `ReplaceRepeated` operator `//.` instead of `/.`?

Comment: @Kuba - beat me by seconds. Regarding the LHS, there are also various options. One *could* execute the `x->z` replacement first. The replacement operator take three arguments after all.

Comment: Using the `Extend Selection` functionality of the front end, one can see that `/.` is [left-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Non-associativity) btw...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has a trivial answer, ReplaceAll is not associative!

```
( x + y /. x -> y ) /. y -> z
```

resulting in

> 2z

whereas

```
x + y /. (x -> y /. y -> z)
```

> y+z

Same is true for *ReplaceRepeated*.

Comment: As [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Definition) is normally defined as a property of a [binary relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) I think it would be nicer to have an example such as `x + y /. x -> y /. y -> z`, which of course shows exactly the same behaviour...